# Sum numbers in multidimentional array in Python with recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to sum numbers in multidimentional array using recursion in Python:

```
tab = [7, 5, [3, 6, [2]], 7, [1, [2, 3, [4]], 9, 2], 4]
```

I have tried few things, for example this:

```
sum(map(sum, tab))
```

It works for simple arrays, e.g. `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`, but it doesn't work for the one on top. I get this error:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
tab = [7, 5, [3, 6, [2]], 7, [1, [2, 3, [4]], 9, 2], 4]

def r_sum(tab):
    return sum(r_sum(item) if isinstance(item, list) else item for item in tab)

r_sum(tab)
# 55
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following recursive algorithm:

```
tab = [7, 5, [3, 6, [2]], 7, [1, [2, 3, [4]], 9, 2], 4]

def sumLst(l):
    sum = 0
    for ele in l:
        if type(ele) in [float, int]:
            sum += ele
        else:
            sum += sumLst(ele)
    return sum
print(sumLst(tab))
```

Comment: I think `if isinstance(ele, (float, int))` is neater here. Also I think you just need to check if `ele` is a `list` in this case, then you recurse if it is.

Comment: @RoadRunner Personally I find `type(ele) in [float, int]` more readable, since with `isinstance(ele, (float, int))` I always assume on first sight that you want to check against a tuple. However in case you prefer feel free to use your statement. There is no real argument against it ;)